# Validation rule for when the Status picklist value of "Assign to Development" a picklist value for "Development Type" must be selected. Please help

Tags: picklist, validation-rule, validation

AND(
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Assign to Development"),
OR(
ISBLANK(Development_Type__c)
)
)

Error: Field Development_Type__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ISBLANK` with a picklist value, but you can write:

```
ISPICKVAL(Development_Type__c,"")
```

The final formula should look like:

```
AND( ISPICKVAL(Status, "Assign to Development"),
     ISPICKVAL(Development_Type__c, "") 
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much this worked :)